# How to identify invisible faces?

Tags: modeling, faces, 3d-printing

I exported very simple model of pencils organizer, sliced by Cura and tried to print, but when I get to "1st floor", 3D printer tries creating full layer within triangle sections like there was some face. I see nothing weird in the model, so I wonder where this is comming from. I used just simple methods to create model - add plane, extrude vertices and solidify faces individually. If somebody experienced such issue, please advice some way to fix it. Thanks. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7qtj7cuqwvitzo/myorganizer.blend?dl=0

[image: screenshot Blender 2.72]

Comment: did you enable the 3d print addon? it has many checks for this task.

Comment: I tried with your file, and that addon above, there is something "intersecting" also elsewhere. 3d printing software can even go over some minor error, but some other will cause printing issues...

Comment: Your model has non-manifold geometry, which is probably at the root of all your troubles. It's a wonder your slicer agreed to slice this at all. You should probably either fix the issues manually, import and fix your model in a 3rd party program like MeshMixer or NetFabb.

Comment: Thank you for replies. Yes its probably worth to use 3d print addon, meanwhile I fixed model on NetFabb and it seems Ok. I thought this problem could be related to flipping normals when I did solidifying faces inside triangular sections. In fact as I foud out the resulting print from Cura was more ridiculous. It filled entire triangle space, not just single layer. I wonder also how to discover manifold issues. I found just very little practical info about this...

Comment: Related to [non-manifold geometry](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7914/1245). Also take a look at [cleaning up mesh](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/cleanup.html). There's also [MeshLint addon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39385/1245) mentioned here which may help you too.